# Laravel and Vuejs axios delete gives no error but doesnt delete

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I created a web route that must delete a contact based on a specific id and it looks like this:

```
Route::delete('/api/deleteContact/{id}', 'ContactController@destroy');
```

Then inside the controller, I have the following:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // delete a contact by id
    return response()->json(Contact::whereId($id), 200);
}
```

Inside one of my blade template files, I call the Vue component which displays the list of contacts:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="contact in contacts">
            <td> {{ contact.id }} </td>
            <td> {{ contact.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ contact.phone }} </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button @click="deleteContact(contact.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The delete button calls the deleteContact method and received the contact id in question.

The method looks like this:

```
deleteContact(id){
    axios.delete('/api/deleteContact/' + id)
    .then(res => {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
            if(this.contacts[i].id == id) {
                this.contacts.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

When I click to delete, the promise(then) occurs, however, after refreshing the page, I noticed that nothing was deleted and I see no errors in the console.

How can I successfully delete the contact based on the id passed in the deleteContact function ?

Comment: Contact::whereId($id) this will not delete, you have to add ->delete() at the end

Comment: I cannot believe that I failed to noticed that. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append delete at the end of query like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // delete a contact by id
    return response()->json(Contact::where('id',$id)->delete(), 200);
}
```